# CSS: working with box borders

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the white box on [this page](http://wix.com), Where it says "your success".

```css
body{
  background-color:#DFDFDF;
  }
.index_whitebox{
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 60%;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="index_whitebox">
  </div>
```

I assume there's no `border-style` and I use % for mobile compatibility. I can't seem to get the border right.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you cant get it right? Can you be more specific? Like is the border-radius too little? ..etc

Comment: @Srijith somehow the guy who answered managed to select that element and i haven't been able to do so in hours, issue solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in 'inspect element' you can actually see how they've coded it. I bunched together the main bits they use, as some used a CSS file and others were inline.

```
.class1 {
    left: 1px;
    width: 302px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 445px;
    height: 378px;
}

.class2 {
    left: 1px;
    width: 302px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 445px;
    height: 378px;
}

.class3{
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

It's all in here:

[image]

Comment: Seriously how did you inspect that? if I put my element inspector on the box i select  `.s11inlineContent, .s11bg` using chrome, seriously how u did it?

Comment: I just tried using firefox, can't select that element, how you did it?

Comment: I've added a picture to show how I selected it. Basically you're selecting one of the nested divs instead of the box itself, just hover over the different bits of code and it'll highlight the one that wraps around the whole box. I hope this helps.